# Empty a div with class name in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have following "div" on which i have to run jquery operation

```
<div class="analytical_base_tables">(content reside here)</div>
```

i want to empty the above "div" by using following jquery statement

```
$("div.analytical_base_tables").empty();
```

but above code isn't working. it is working when i am using following jquery statement

```
$("div").empty();
```

but it is not my requirement i want to empty the div by using classname as following statement (also written above)

```
  $("div.analytical_base_tables").empty();
```

please help

Comment: Surely it would take about 3 seconds to try?

Comment: What happened to "I wonder what this code does *runs code* Oh, I see!"

Answer (score 2):

ehh yes it does see [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

**update**

if your question is what is better to use, you should use the `.ClassName` selector

Comment: No you shouldn't use `div.ClassName` http://jsperf.com/jquery-class-vs-tag-qualfied-class-selector/5

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder ohh that's embarrassing. Thnx for the link! update my post

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

```
$("div.ClassName").html('');
```